# Create a Custom Unsubscribe Page with Smart Capture

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, smart-capture, unsubscribe

I am trying to follow this document to create a custom landing page for Unsubscribe.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_a_custom_unsubscribe_page_using_smart_capture.htm&type=5

But I am unable to see these below options like Processing tab etc.
-Click the Processing tab.
-Select Subscriber Master Unsub in the Action 1 drop-down menu.
-In the Subscriber Email Address field, click the Fields drop-down menu and select 
  Email Address.

Is it something which I am missing in my profile or the document is too old and needs to be updated.

Comment: cloud dot did you get any resolution to this?

Comment: @pragyanshukukreti  The document is old it seems. I didn't get any resolution on this